# bash: test if associative array entry exists, create if doesn't, increment value if does

Tags: bash

What would be the bash code after:

```
declare -A map
```

to do the following:

1) if a string does not yet exist in the map, create the entry for it and set its count (value) to 1

2) if the string already exists in the map, increment the count (value) by 1?

Am using post version 4.0 of Bash.

Based on @that other guy's answer, I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=("a" "b" "a")
declare -a map

for i in ${input[@]}
do
  let 'map[$i]++'
  echo "map[$i]=${map[$i]}"
done
```

And when run it produces the following -- does NOT seem to work:

```
$ maptest
map[a]=1
map[b]=2
map[a]=3
```

Comment: `declare -a map` declares `map` to be a list (i.e. indexed by integers). It's not the same as `declare -A map`, which does create an associative array.

Comment: Thanks @rici.   I was wrong on my version of Bash (from cygwin, it's 3.1.17, even though I just got cygwin installed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this would be:

```
let '++map[$key]'
```

This relies on the fact that an unset value is considered 0.

Comment: Thanks, am trying what you said with an echo statement that is obviously wrong, using:  for i in ${input[@]}
do
  let 'map[$i]++'
  echo "map[$i]=$map[$i]"
done

Comment: @Ray In your question you said `declare -A map` while in your example you use `declare -a map`.

Comment: I see.  I actually do have Bash 3.1.17.  I falsely assumed that loading latest cygwin would give me a Bash shell that was more recent than 7+ years old.  I might rev that but other part of team will be using the script.  Is it possible that you edit your answer, just slightly change the text?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing.  I need you to edit the text just so I can award you point and mark it as an answer.  Any slight text edit will do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample in the (edited) question works correctly when used with `declare -A` instead of `declare -a`. So the accepted answer is correct.

However if used with `set -u` aka `set -o nounset`, it will fail with `map: unbound variable`

The solution is to use `declare -iA` and the `+=` operator, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

input=("a" "b" "a")
declare -iA map

for i in ${input[@]}
do
  map[$i]+=1
  echo "map[$i]=${map[$i]}"
done
```

Which produces the following output:

```
map[a]=1
map[b]=1
map[a]=2
```